# Trouble with converting to apk

Tags: android, apk

I created a program with mit app inventor and I wanted to edit androidmanifest.xml and i decompile the Apk then after editing I zipped it into Rar...The problem is that I cannot convert it to Apk again after editing

Answer (score 0):

First things first, remember that an apk is a specially packed .jar file that has been signed to verify that it has not been edited since it was created.

By unzipping and editing the file, you have made the signature invalid.

You nor need to resign the file with your own certificate to make it a valid apk again. It is easiest to do it via your Android IDE, but you can also do it using a keytool